# Select stream to input

Tags: c++, if-statement, iostream

I need very simple thing in C++: use one from two input streams - file or stdin - depending on certain condition.
Like that:

```
istream s;  
if (true)  
     s = cin;  
else  
    s = ifstream(argv[1]);  

while (s.read()) /* ... */
```

Hope the idea is clear.

First of all, it seems it is unable to declare `istream` variable (`istream` because it is common for `ifstream` and `ci`n) without connection to any device or file or whatever.
The second thing is it is unable to declare `istream` variable at all, compiler says:

```
error: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected
```

And therefore which class have I to use for that purposes then?

So, failed to understand. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I notice that this is your first post on Stack Overflow. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) you can read how to ask questions, evaluate answers and possibly accept the answer you consider the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an `istream*` and then in the if assign either to `&cin` or to the address of your `ifstream`. In the following lines, if you want to avoid the ugly syntax of dereferencing your pointer, you can declare a `istream&`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Luca mentioned, you will likely need to use an istream pointer or reference. The reference is a bit trickier because you can only initialize it once and can't change it later. Another discussion of this topic can be found [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/98719-defaulting-ifstream-variable-standard-input.html)